# Handle mobile data connection changes when executing data sending in background service

Tags: android, android-intentservice

I am trying to implement **`IntentService`**, where I would like to execute a HTTP request.

- How can I handle connection changes (e.g. network failure) during the data transfer?
- Is it possible to continue in process when network is available?

I don't want to ask for code I just need advice how to do that. I appreciate every help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to break up the data transfer into blocks and implement a loop to handle the data transfer, then check for network connectivity on each iteration. For example:

```
foreach(String block as data) {
    if(isConnected()) {
        // Transfer block
    } else {
        // Not connected
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need functionality like e.g. Google Play update application - application is downloading. When your connection is broken, process is waiting for connection and if connection is restored downloading continues but not from beginning.

Comment: I believe the Play Store application uses something similar to this to achieve this functionality. Instead of a break when not connected, it would be simple to modify this to display a message, store the position of the loop then set up a timer to check periodically for connection and resume the operation from the same position if the connection is re-established.